# Covariance of a random variable and its mean

Tags: covariance, standard-deviation, means

I want to find the value of $cov(X, \bar{X})$.
If I input this in the formula, I will get:
$\sum (X - \bar{X})(\bar{X} - \bar{X})/N = 0 \:\:\:\:\:\:(\because \bar{\bar{X}} = \bar{X})$

Edit: Here $X$ is a set of random variables. I.e. The values $X_i$ themselves can vary randomly based on some underlying distribution. I am not trying to calculate this for one fixed set of X values.

But this is obviously incorrect. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

$cov(X,\bar{X})=E(X\bar{X})-E(X)E(\bar{X})$  However $\bar{X}$ is a constant, so $E(X\bar{X})=\bar{X}E(X)=\bar{X}^2$, leading to the final result $cov(X,\bar{X})=0$.

This shouldn't be too surprising, since $cov(X,C)=0$ for any constant $C$.

Comment: Can you check the edit I made? I have added some more details.

Comment: If $X$ is a set of random variables, what do you mean by $\bar{X}$ or $\bar{\bar{X}}$?

Comment: So basically, I have n data points with labels $X_i$ . And they can be predicted as $\hat{X}_i$. I want to find the value of $cov(X, \hat{X})$. In certain case, the value of $\hat{X} $ for all of $X_i$s will be $\bar{X}$.

Comment: Okay can you tell me if $cov(X_i, 1/N*\sum_{j=1}^n X_j) = 1/N*\sum_{j=1}^n cov(X_i, X_j)$

Comment: Can you see section 1.3, average estimator: $cov(\bar{y}, y_i)$ $http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/advmethods/notes/df.pdf

Comment: I am not sure how covarince between sets of random variables is defined.

Comment: Ah okay! Did you see the link?

Comment: I looked at it, got an attack of MEGO, and I don't see a definition.

Answer (score -1):

Cov(x,y) = E(xy)−E(x)E(y)= E(x−E(x))(y−E(y)))

Cov(x,x̅) = E[(X–µX)(x̅–µx̅] = E[xx̅]-E(x)E(x̅)

Use x−E(x)=ϵ and x̅= Hx, so x̅−E(x̅)=Hx−E(Hx)=H(x−E(x))=Hϵ. Then
Cov(x,x̅) = E[(x−E(x))(x̅−E(x̅))^T] = E(ϵϵTH) = (σ^2)H
The i,i diagonal element of the LHS is Cov(x_i,x̅_i), while the i,i diagonal element of the RHS is (σ^2)h_i,i